# a is undefined when code is put into a function

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I have a scapy sniffer that runs fine when its not in a function like so:

```py
from scapy.all import *


a = 0

def f(packet):
    global a
    a+=1



s = sniff(prn=f, timeout=1, iface='en0', store=0)
print(a)
```

but when I put the code into a function like this:

```py
from scapy.all import *


def sniffer():
    a = 0

    def f(packet):
        global a
        a+=1



    s = sniff(prn=f, timeout=1, iface='en0', store=0)
    return a

print(sniffer())
```

it returns:

```
File "/Users/test.py", line 9, in f
    a+=1
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

can seem to fix this so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Read about global, nonlocal keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not a global variable as it's defined inside the `sniffer()` function. To do what you want you should use `nonlocal` instead of `global`:

```
from scapy.all import *


def sniffer():
    a = 0

    def f(packet):
        nonlocal a
        a+=1



    s = sniff(prn=f, timeout=1, iface='en0', store=0)
    return a

print(sniffer())
```

More info about the `nonlocal` statment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#the-nonlocal-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error as there is no global variable `a`.

There are a few options:

- declare `a` outside of all functions to make it `global`
- in function `f()`, remove `global` from `a` and initialize it with value to make it a local variable.
- If you still want to use the variable `a` from the outer function, then remove `global` keyword while accessing and make it `mutable`